# Italics and emphasis in LyX

Tags: fonts, lyx, bold

I have problems with the output to PDF from a LyX document. When I write a lemma or a theorem, its output is in bold instead of italics. Also, when I write a word in italics its output is in bold instead. How can I fix that?
My fonts are:
David CLM, Miriam Mono CLM, Simple CLM, in that order.

Comment: Make a minimal document showing this problem. Then,  export to LaTeX code and remove  irrelevant code to produce that problem  (comments, babel package, etc...)  so it is still compilable with texworks or any other latex editor and still show the problem, and finally, edit the question to **show us that code**.

Comment: @Yoav please read https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample